# MFC - WebBrowser control: Ctrl-F does not search?

Tags: mfc, webbrowser-control, visual-c++-2008

I use webbrowser control to embed a browser in the app (source: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3919/Using-the-WebBrowser-control-simplified). When I load web page from URL and type Ctrl-F, the dialog pops up correctly and search works well. But if I load html as string, the search does not work. Whatever string I enter it always reports not found. What could be the issue and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question,
When you click Ctrl+F then Find And Replace window dialog will open. There's a Find Options, Click on (+) symbol in Find options, then it'll expand then you will 4 checkboxes like Match case,Match whole word, etc. Unticked both checkboxes, after that you will find any string in your code.

Thanks
Please like my answer if your problem resolve.

Comment: I edit the question based on new discovery. If you could help, thanks.